# Java Canvas to XML Layout "Hello World" syntax

Tags: java, xml, canvas

I have a simple xml layout that looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ColorWheel1Activity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="Color Wheel 1"
        android:id="@+id/Target"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and a java script in the form of:

```
public class ColorWheel1Activity extends Activity {

    Paint black = new Paint();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        black.setStrokeWidth(5);

        canvas.drawOval(100, 200, 1000, 1100, black); 

        //don'tknow what to put here
}
```

I want to draw the oval on the canvas to the inside of the `ImageView` (android:id Target) in the xml layout but don't know how to do this. I have tried `setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_wheel1.xml)` which sets the xml layout without drawing the picture. I have also tried `setContnetView(canvas)` and a few of it's variants which set the entire screen as the canvas, displaying the oval but none of the xml Layout. I have made attempts to locate the Target `ImageView` with `findViewById()` but these either crashed the app or did nothing.

I do not want to create an entire xml Layout in java.

Answer (score 0):

> I have made attempts to locate the Target ImageView with findViewById() but these either crashed the app or did nothing.

Im not sure how locating the Target Imageview would cause a crash; this definitely seems like the way to go. Try getting a reference to Target, like so

```
ImageView Target = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Target);
```

Then set the bitmap you created to that ImageView:

```
Target.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I tried those two lines substituted in for my comment and then those two lines followed by setContentView(R.layout. ...) both produced errors

Comment: ERROR:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference